# Fixed width and fluid div side by side with bootstrap 3.0

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

```
<div class="row">    
    <div class="col-xs-2"></div> //This need as fixed width of 200px
    <div class="col-xs-10"></div>
</div>
```

I need first div with fixed width of 200px and other div in percentage with twitter bootstrap 3.0

Answer (score 8):

If you look the bootstrap3 rules, you'll see:

```
.col-xs-2 { width: 16.6667%; }
.col-xs-10 { width: 83.3333%; }
```

If you want a fixed width for the first item, you'll have to override the width of the second too (can't mix px and percent).

I wouln't use `.col-xs-*` classes in this case, but a classic layout like:

```
.item1 { float: left; width: 200px; }
.item2 { display: block; margin-left: 200px; }
```

Hope this helps!